# C++ library for mesh to mesh intersection: what is available?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, intersection, mesh

I need to calculate volume intersection and penetration depth between 3D triangular meshes (e.g. in .obj format),  but I am quite new to computational geometry.

In a previous post ([Mesh to mesh intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973402/mesh-to-mesh-intersections)) and from my google search, I found a few C++ libraries which might be appropriate to do the job:

- CGAL
- PQP
- libigl
- SWIFT

Though, I am not sure which one could be the most appropriate for a beginner. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[libigl](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/) as of version 1.1 has robust mesh boolean operations in `igl/boolean/mesh_boolean.h`. This uses either an implementation using CGAL's exact arithmetic kernel or a wrapper of [cork](https://github.com/gilbo/cork) (another option for you).

For now, libigl also contains a patched version of cork in `libigl/external/cork`, which greatly improves robustness.

While implementing libigl's boolean ops, I found that cork is faster but does not always produce the correct result (specifically, it fails to resolve all intersections).

Libigl, using CGAL as a backend, is the most robust and still fast compared to converting a mesh to CGAL's `Nef_polyhedron`, conducting CSG operations and converting back to a mesh. This final conversion would be possible only if the result is manifold. Instead, libigl only uses CGAL for exact triangle-triangle intersection and 2D meshing. Correct, non-manifold output is no problem.

Libigl's interface is very simple and familiar to users of [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org). For example, to find the intersection between a solid mesh with vertices in the rows of `VA` and triangles indices in the rows of `FA` and another mesh `(VB,FB)` and store the output in a new mesh `(VC,FC)`:

```
#include <igl/boolean/mesh_boolean.h>
...
igl::mesh_boolean(VA,FA,VB,FB,MESH_BOOLEAN_TYPE_UNION,VC,FC);
```

Answer (score 0):

One additional possibility is to use open-source C++ library [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme). It can read and write meshes in Wavefront format (.obj) and robustly perform Boolean operations (intersection, union, difference) on meshes: [documentation](https://meshinspector.github.io/MeshLib/html/group__BooleanGroup.html) of the appropriate functions.

As far as I know, Boolean operations in `MeshLib` are faster than in `CGAL` and `libigl`, see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhJ9Y07MfoE) of MeshInspector application based on `MeshLib`.